# pass eventhandler from combobox to parentcontrol (simple panel)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, eventhandler

i want to pass some eventhandlers from a combobox (e.g. SelectedIndexChanged) to my panel, which is the parent control.
The solution should be something like you can add an eventhandler in the designer to the panel. This eventhandler acts exactly like the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox which is placed on the panel.

So that in code i dont have to make

```
myPanel.internalComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged +=  new System.EventHandler(function);
```

i want it be like this

```
myPanel.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(function);
```

So I want to call  "function"  if the selected index is changed in the combobox, from the eventhandler of the panel :)

I hope someone can help me

Regards Andreas

Comment: Sounds like custom `MyPanel: Panel` to me. If you add events to it they will be visible in the designer and you can add event handlers from there. Note: there is always line you don't want to have, it's just hidden inside `InitializeComponents()`, perhaps it's not worth the effort? Typically this kind of functionality would be a `UserControl` job, those are more suitable for such customizations.

Comment: finally i solved my problem very easily by creating a custom eventhandler whis is called by the original eventhandler of my combobox